# java multiple connections between server and one client

Tags: java, networking

I'm trying to make like a skype-instant messager, my idea for it is to have
one server which handles multiple connections for the clients. What I now have is a friend list etc, but now I want to create Threads both for server and client to handle a conversation. The problem is that I need multiple connections between a server and one client for every conversation(I think). but i dont think it's possible. Does someone have another way for doing this or maybe a way to make multiple connections between the server and a client?

Thanks for helping me out

PS: English is not my main language so please excuse me for my grammar.

Comment: What did you try any *why* do you think it's not possible to have one sochet per 'call'?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best is that you always make one tcp connection from each client to the server, that way if your client is behind a firewall or router the connection can be established anyway.

Then you need to define a protocol with control messages, like "create new conversation with ...". And the server can generate a guid for each new conversation, then client can receive and send messages togheter with the conversation id always through one connection.

**Update:**

To answer the original question: yes, you can make multiple connections between client and server. Each connection should be opened from the client to the server port, once established, each one will have a different port. You can make a thread to deal with each connection or have on thread dealing with all connection using non-blocking calls.

Comment: well, my goal was to do it all in one port, but thanks for the suggestion with the protocol messages! gonna use that